# Calculations using subtotals and totals

Tags: r, dplyr, subtotal

I have a dataset where I calculate weightings based on total mpg and apply this weighting to a constant to calculate column "distribution".  What I want to do is, to allocate another constant of 100 to only those cars where the maker is Mercedes.  So I first calculate where each individual car stands as of the total and allocate 1000 called distribution plus another 100 on just the Mercedes cars.  How can I do this?

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
a <- mtcars
setDT(a, keep.rownames = TRUE)
colnames(a)[1] <- "Car"
b <- a %>%
  select(Car,mpg) %>%
  mutate(Weighting = mpg / sum(mpg)) %>%
  mutate(Distribution = Weighting * 1000)
```

Example output: Couldn't figure out how to get it in R but here is an excel image that shows the expected results.
[image: Wanted Output]

The only solution that comes to mind is to calculate it separately and assign it as a constant.

Your help is more than appreciated.
Aksel

Comment: Please provide few example rows as a sample and desired output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for taking up peoples time, but it seems like the easiest solution for me was to first calculate the total Mercedes balance and assign it to a variable and then do my remaining calculations by referring to my variable.

If anyone faces a similar issue, please drop me a line and I would me more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

add an `ifelse`?
and match the mercedes cars with `substr(Car, 1, 4) %in% "Merc"`

```
b <- a %>%
  select(Car,mpg) %>%
  mutate(Merc_Weighting = ifelse(substr(Car, 1, 4) %in% "Merc", mpg / sum(mpg[substr(Car, 1, 4) %in% "Merc"]), NA)) %>%
  mutate(Merc_Distribution = Merc_Weighting * 100)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I want the 100 to be distributed based on the weighted value of mercedes's mpg.  Just added an excel spreadsheet to demonstrate.

Comment: still not clear to me what you want, where does the 100 get added and to what?

Comment: the 1000 gets distributed to all.  The 100 only to the Mercedes.  So the first distribution column you see adds up to 1000 and the Mercedes distribution column adds up to 100.  So the 100 needs to be distributed amongst the Mercedes.  So not 100 for each Merc.